# Using a loop value as part of a Variable name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, variables

Is there a way to shorten this section of code to substitute the numeric part of the driver[n]claim[n]date within a nested loop? I'm  8 days into SQL programming but this looks pretty clunky from my programming days 35 years ago :) Any help gladly accepted.

```
Start of loop
 nested loop

CASE WHEN Driver1Claim1Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim1Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim1Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver1Claim2Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim2Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim2Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver1Claim3Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim3Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim3Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver1Claim4Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim4Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim4Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver1Claim5Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim5Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim5Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver1Claim6Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim6Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver1Claim6Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver2Claim1Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim1Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim1Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver2Claim2Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim2Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim2Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver2Claim3Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim3Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim3Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver2Claim4Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim4Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim4Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver2Claim5Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim5Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim5Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+CASE WHEN Driver2Claim6Date BETWEEN t.PolicyStarted AND t.PolicyEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim6Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  WHEN Driver2Claim6Type = 'At fault' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 end of nested loop
End of outer loop
```

Comment: please make your code more readable.

Comment: The problem is, someone's designed the table wrong. In a well designed system, all data of the same "type" ought to be in the *same* column. Then, you'd also have other columns to contain (1 or 2) and (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6) and the names of those columns would tell us what that data, currently embedded in metadata, *represents*

Comment: what happens when they need 7 claims? what if there are more than 2 vehicles involved?

Comment: Hi Jeremy - The driver number refers to the number of drivers on this policy not those involved in the claim. this is just an extract as the number of drivers on the policy maxes out at 6.  If the facility to perform a nested loop exists then I can just edit the iterations to accommodate the necessary numbers.

Comment: qxg - apologies but this is just an extract of a script I have inherited and am thinking of ways to make it  more compact.

Comment: @Doug with this design, there is really no good way. As others have said, a table redesign to normalize the data a bit more would be the only way.

Comment: Well you don't have to permanently and physically redesign the database.   You could build a temp table or cte that unpivots all those drivers and claims and then work on that instead of the original table.

Comment: You could populate a cursor / temp table with dynamic SQL strings for the weird column names in your table then put it through a loop.  The problem that complicates this is your database's strange schema.  You should have separate tables for "Drivers" and "Claims".  Look up Database Normalization.  If you have any control in how this system is set up, you should really urge them to normalize this before you put too much data into it.  This system is going to cause some more headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with the comments that suggest proper normalization would be the best way to solve this problem.  With that being said, there are solutions that you could use that don't involve schema modifications...

1. As one comeent stated, you could use Temporary tables, a local table variable or a CTE to `unpivot` your data, thereby making it more properly normalized for the life of your stored procedure.  This will make it easier to work with, but will add additional overhead to the stored procedure.
2. You could use dynamic SQL to build your query.  This will allow you to "insert" loop iteration counters into your column names.  There are some drawbacks to dynamic SQL.  But I use it in many situations.  It can be a good tool to have in your tool box when used properly.  Here is [an article about Dynamic SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) that should be useful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - as I said I'm a complete newbie to SQL so will start a bit of reading and see if I can utilise some of this advice - I don't have any control over the structure of the database - which is probably a good thing with my knowledge level at present.